# Variable scope value along with URL helper rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

In my routes.rb, I have configured routes as:

```
scope "/(:city)", constraints: {city: /ny|dc/} do
    resources :bookings do
        collection do
            get 'checkout'
            ...
end
```

I want my URL to be `/ny/bookings/checkout`. If I hardcode it in my controller, it works fine (`redirect_to '/ny/bookings/checkout'`). 
But I want to use URL helpers, as I think that would be easier to manage in future instead of hardcoding in many places. How can I pass the `city` scope along with the helper, so as to get the correct URL? The value of `city` is stored in the session.

Using `redirect_to checkout_bookings(session[:city])` generates a URL `/bookings/checkout?city=ny`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
redirect_to checkout_bookings_path(city: 'ny')
# => "/ny/bookings/checkout"
```

Comment: Glad to help. And really, no need to feel bad about not knowing a Rails convention by heart... There are a lot of them.

Comment: Thank you!! I have been searching for this for days. I tried to find this info in  Routing from the Outside In and never even came close.